# e.argument in listview not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have linkbuttons in my listview that fires the function "ItemCommand" when clicked. "e.CommandArgument.ToString()" is suppose to equal the item that I choose but sometimes it shows the correct item and sometimes it is not. Why?

```
 <AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr class="UserAltTemplate" >
        <td>
           <%-- <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Login") %>'  style='<%# GetUserNameStyle() %>'/>--%>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Eval("Login").ToString()) %>'
            style='<%# GetUserNameStyle() %>' Text='<%# Eval("Login") %>' CommandArgument='<%#  Eval("Login") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </td>



protected void ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    string Target = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on CommandName  that if it has a command argument or not. You can change the markup to something like:

```
      <asp:LinkButton ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Eval("Login").ToString()) %>'
            style='<%# GetUserNameStyle() %>' Text='<%# Eval("Login") %>' 
CommandName="Login" CommandArgument='<%#  Eval("Login") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

And in the code:

```
protected void ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "Login"))
        {
            string Target = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

You can look [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewcommandeventargs.aspx) for details.